# How to store MySQLi bind_result value for further processing?

Tags: mysqli

In the below code,I can echo $count in bind_result by using while loop(commented in the code). But instead I want to keep that value in the $count variable for further processing instead of just printing the value. How do I hold the value for $count?

```
 /*......mysqli connection...*/

 $stmt =$mysqli->prepare("select count(*) from tab where rtd_id=? ");     
 $stmt->bind_param('i',$id);
 $id = 1;
 $stmt->execute();    
 $stmt->bind_result($count);

 /*while($stmt->fetch())
 {
   echo $count;
 }*/

 if($count>0)
 {
   //DO SOMETHING
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need a loop here.

```
$stmt->bind_result($count);
$stmt->fetch();
if($count>0)
{
   //DO SOMETHING
}
```